# Is it possible to use StratifiedKFold from sklearn in multi input Neural Networks?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras, cross-validation

I have a dataset that can be passed to a multi input neural network in the shape of a python *dictionary* or a *list*:

**Example**:

```
#dict
{'input1': X1, 'input2': X2, 'input3': X3}, {'output': Y}
#list
[ X1, X2, X3], y
```

Now I would like to use **K-fold cross validation** to estimate the performance of my model. Do you think I can use `StratifiedKFold` from `sklearn` as in this mono-input example?

```
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
  # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # Fit the model
    model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
    # evaluate the model
    scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
```

Otherwise, what would be the best way?

Comment: You can use SKF also. But as I know it is better to covert dictionary to pandas dataframe.

Also, sklearn supports KerasClassifier/KerasRegressor so you can rewrite your code like here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-keras-deep-learning-models-scikit-learn-python/

Comment: Yes but they don't work with multi input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

skf.split() returns you indices and it depends only on Y:

```
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

So you can pass any X array here (even X1 for layer 1 converted to dataframe or synthetic X). Then you take your

```
train_index
```

and

```
test_index
```

and filter all your inputs.

Again, skf() depends on your Y only. So the goal is to pass proper Y and get indices.

Other way: union all you inputs in outputs in one dataframe and keep column names for each layer. In this case you have one 'big' X. Split it firstly train_index and test_index and then split into X1, X2 and X3 using column names you saved above.

Comment: I did the exact same this morning! Anyway I will post this as solution as it is working how it should! Actually I passed only the Y:   `kfold = KFold(n_splits=5)
   
`for train_indices, test_indices in kfold.split(Y):
    train_1, train_2, train_3, train_4 = data[0][train_indices], data[1][train_indices], data[2][train_indices], data[3][train_indices]`

Comment: Good to hear, Francesco! Thanks!

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro can I use shuffel=True in the StratifiedKFold when splitting on Y only?

Comment: @Daisy: I don't see why not... Did you try it?

Comment: maybe it is a dumb question, but I thought it will shuffel the Ys only.

Comment: It is not an option in case of using the StratifiedKFold. A solution could be found: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7126

Comment: @Daisy
With or without shuffling you get train and test indices. Every index value reflects exactly the same value/row from the original dataset.